Full Screen background image in React
I'm trying to create a website using typescript + React but I'm having some issues. I have embedded a video into my website that I want to be the background for the first section but no matter what I do there are white borders and both sides of my video. I'm very new to React so if someone could help me out that would be great!
Current state of website
No matter what I do I can't seem to fill in the two columns on either side.
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

I've already set the margins and padding to 0
style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    zIndex: -1,
                    objectFit: "cover",
                    pointerEvents: "none",
                  }}

I've also set the height and width of the video to be 100%.
Even when I change my css and set background-color to black the columns on either side still don't change color. I'm aware this might be a super novice mistake but I'm spinning my wheels and would love a pointer.

Can you please provide the code of the section where you wanna add a video as background?

// App.jsx

function App() {
    return (
        <main
            style={{
                height: "100vh",
                position: "relative",
            }}
        >
            <video
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4"
                autoPlay
                muted
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    objectFit: "cover",

                    position: "absolute",
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    zIndex: -1,
                    opacity: 0.7,
                }}
            />
            <div
                style={{
                    minHeight: "100vh",
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                }}
            >
                <h1
                    style={{
                        fontSize: "50px",
                    }}
                >
                    Video is playing
                </h1>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
export default App


/* index.css */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



use ObjectFit property
